# What's the meaning of sortBy in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new in AgularJS, and when I tried to do the practice:

JS file:

```
function CustomersController() {
    this.sortBy = 'name';
    this.reverse = false;

    this.customers= [{joined: '2000-12-02', name:'John', city:'Chandler', orderTotal: 9.9956}, {joined: '1965-01-25',name:'Zed', city:'Las Vegas', orderTotal: 19.99},{joined: '1944-06-15',name:'Tina', city:'New York', orderTotal:44.99}, {joined: '1995-03-28',name:'Dave', city:'Seattle', orderTotal:101.50}];
    this.doSort = function(propName) {
       this.sortBy = propName;
       this.reverse = !this.reverse;
    };
}
```

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
    <title>Iterating Over Data</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="CustomersController">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
    <br /><br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
            <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.joined | date }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <span>Total customers: {{ customers.length }}</span>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the webpage I can click the table's head and sort by name. So I want to know that what's the meaning of sortBy ? Is it a built-in variable in $scope? I tried to change its name (like "sortby") and it doesn't sort (just reverse). If it is, where could I find the built-in functions of $scope? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `sortBy` is just the name of the variable and is not built into the $scope. You could use anything. Notice that `sortBy` is referenced in 2 places:

In the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
```

And in your controller in 2 places:

```
// This initializes the sort order
this.sortBy = 'name';
// This sets the new sort order when a user clicks on the table heding
this.sortBy = propName;
```

You are free to use another name for sortBy, you just need to replace it in all of those places.

However, orderBy is specific to the ng-repeat, so you can't change that name. For more information you can check out the last example on this page:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Very appreciate for it! So it means the AngularJS uses "orderBy" to define an order action, and sortBy function is the function that do the sort?